# comparing three diagonal array and find which two are most similar

Tags: c#, arrays, statistics, similarity

I have three diagonal arrays `A,B,C` all are `double` of size `508X508`. All the values above the principal diagonal are non-zero, and every other cell holds zero.

Data in both `A and B` are collected from sensor in Day-1 and then Day-2. Meanwhile, the optimal data are stored in `C`.

My question is how to find which of the arrays `A,B` is more similar to `C` ???

What is the best statistical method to achieve that, if possible maybe a C# code snap ?

Comment: How about "brute force", like `double deviation = 0; for(var i = 0; i < outerLength; i++) { for(var j = 0; j < innerLength; j++) { deviation += (a[i][j] - c[i][j]); } }` and then check, which `deviation` is closer to zero? Or how would you determine "similarity" by hand? Is `[[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]` more or less similar to `[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]` than `[[1, 1, 1, 1, 6]]`? With the above method, they'd be equaly similar. Is that, what you want, or should a single but bigger deviation weigh more or less than a broader but smaller (per item) deviation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Corak pointed you to the right way. Just select a distance measure, compute the total sum of distances for each matrix.

Try something like this

```
    public double ComputeArrayDistance(double[,] firstArray, double[,] secondArray)
    {
        // some quick and dirty guardClauses to prevent hedaches 
        if (firstArray.GetLength(0) != firstArray.GetLength(1)) throw new ArgumentException("the first array is not squared ..");
        if (secondArray.GetLength(0) != secondArray.GetLength(1)) throw new ArgumentException("the second array is not squared ..");
        if (firstArray.GetLength(0) != secondArray.GetLength(0)) throw new ArgumentException("the size of two array don't match");

        double totalDistance = 0; 

        // if the array(matrix) is lower triangular
        for(int i = 0; i < firstArray.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++ )
            {
                totalDistance += this.GetDistance(firstArray[i, j], secondArray[i, j]);
            }
        }

        return totalDistance;
    }

    private double GetDistance(double elemOne, double elemTwo)
    {
        // an acceptable measure should be the square of the difference  
        return Math.Pow((elemOne - elemTwo), 2);
    }
```

Comment: As the OP describes it, the significant values are in the upper triangle, so `for(int j = i; j < firstArray.GetLength(1); j++)` should get those.